# Setting backgroundSize to window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so that my background image has a height and width of 100% of the window size.

This works for the width portion:

```
var ht = document.querySelector("html");

ht.style.background = "url('treebg.jpg')";

ht.style.backgroundSize = window.innerWidth + "px";
```

It dose not work when I add the height:

```
var ht = document.querySelector("html");

ht.style.background = "url('treebg.jpg')";

ht.style.backgroundSize = window.innerWidth + "px" +

window.innerHeight + "px";
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There's no space between the two pixel sizes. You'll probably want `background-size: cover` instead anyway, since your with code the image doesn't retain its aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a space after the first "px".

```
var ht = document.querySelector("html");

ht.style.background = "url('treebg.jpg')";

ht.style.backgroundSize = window.innerWidth + "px " + window.innerHeight + "px";
```